# session post to next page

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
 $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
 } // i need to pass this to next page $name.

?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Aug Log In</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form1.css" media="screen"> 
</head>
<body align="center">
    <form action="test1.php" method="post">
    <div class="Upper_Img"><img src="http://localhost/augbanner.gif"/></div><!-- end of Upper_Img -->
    <div class="container">
    <h1> AUG SWIFT TEST </h1>
    <br>
        <label><a href="<?php echo $loginUrl;?>">LOG IN WITH FACEBOOK</a><label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label><a href="">CHANGE FACEBOOK ACCOUNT</a></label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label><input type="name" placeholder="name"/></label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label><input type="email" placeholder="email"/></label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
    </form><!--end of form -->
    <div><!-- end of container -->
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

test1.php

```
<?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['name'];
    }

?>
```

My intention is the pass $name to text1.php, I double checked everything. Why can't I get the $name to pass to next page? Is it something wrong about my html ?

I tried this code, still its not working:

```
$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : false; //get session passing data;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `session_start()` to your next page, but more important, you need to add `name` attributes to your `input`s:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"/>
...
<input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
session_start()
```

in the next page as well.

That means:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['name'];
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're expecting. Here's the code :

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Aug Log In</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
    <form action="test.php" method="post"> // action - test.php
    <h1> AUG SWIFT TEST </h1><br>
       Username : <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="name"/>
       <br><br>
       Email : <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
        <br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to add `name` attribute in `input type`, so that you can get the value from test.php.

**test.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // checks if user submits the form

    $u_name = $_POST['uname']; // Getting the username where user entered 
    $email = $_POST['email']; // Getting the email where user entered

    echo "Your username : " . $u_name ."<br/>";
    echo "Your email : " . $email;

}

?>
```

If you want to use `username` for any of page, just start the session by adding

```
 session_start()
```

at top of the `test.php` &

```
$_SESSION['name']=$u_name;
```

before the `echo`. Hope it helps!

Comment: cant i having error , Notice: Undefined variable: name in
Call Stack

Comment: what am i missing ? i got blank page sometimes.

Comment: i tested your sample it wont work as well in my place

Comment: Did you add `SESSION` too? You want only `username` right?